# OCR Java Wrapper for Windows 7 , JRE 7 and Eclipse

Tags: ocr

I have tried to find the correct steps to make the Tessaract based code work but i face issues with the dlls. I almost researched all OCR questions in Stackoverflow. Below is my configuration,
    Eclipse, JRE 7 , Windows 7. Kindly help me out.Step by step explanation will be helpful.

Comment: This article might help you: http://tphangout.com/?p=18

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version, 1.4.1, which will autoload the DLLs for you.

[Development with Tess4J in NetBeans, Eclipse, and Command-line](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/)

Comment: Do you mean the Tess4j jar version ? Kindly share me the location. Do i need to know if its 64 bit or 32 bit ?